# If $(X_n)$ is a martingale, why do we have $\mathbb E[(H\cdot X)_n]=\mathbb E[X_0]$?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a martingale w.r.t. the filtration $(\mathcal F_n)_n$. Set $$(H\cdot X)_n=\sum_{k=1}^nH_k(X_k-X_{k-1}),$$
where $H$ is predictable i.e. $H_n\in \mathcal F_{n-1}$. Why $$\mathbb E[(H\cdot X)_n]=\mathbb E[X_0] \ \ ?$$

**Try**

$$\mathbb E[(H\cdot X)_n]=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb E[H_k(X_{k+1}-X_k)]=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb E\big[H_k\mathbb E[X_k-X_{k-1}\mid \mathcal F_{k-1}]\big],$$
since $(X_n)$ is a Martingale, we have that $\mathbb E[X_k-X_{k-1}\mid \mathcal F_{k-1}]=0$, so at the end $$\mathbb E[(H\cdot X)_n]=0$$ and not $\mathbb E[X_0]$, I'm I right ?

(this come from the book *Continuous martingale and Brownian motion* third edition of Yor and Revuz).

**Here the whole proof** [image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the error really. Perhaps $(H\cdot X)_n$ is defined differently? I don't think it's true the way it is written (e.g. take $H_n \equiv 1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{E}{\mathbb E}$ In the proof of Proposition 1.3 on page 52 (the proposition before the one you've shown) the book defines $H \cdot X$ to be the process $Y$ where
$$ Y_0 = X_0, \quad Y_n = Y_{n-1} + H_n (X_n - X_{n-1}). $$
This means we actually have
$$ (H \cdot X)_n = X_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n H_k (X_k - X_{k-1}) $$
from which we get $\E[(H \cdot X)_n] = \E[X_0]$. I agree that this is not the standard convention though, and even this book changes convention when it formally defines the stochastic integral. In fact on page 138 it stresses that $K \cdot M$ vanishes at 0.

Comment: In the book I have, they don't make any connexion between $H\cdot X$ and the process $Y$... (I read 3 times the pages before and after, I don't see anywhere a definition of $(H\cdot X)_n$ neither that $H\cdot X=Y$). By the way, what do you mean by "They define $H\cdot X$ to be the process $Y$" ? Do you mean that $H\cdot X=Y$ ?

Comment: @John Proposition 1.3 defines the process $Y$ as I've put in the answer. In the proof it then states "The process $Y$ thus defined is the discrete version of the stochastic integral we will define in Chap. IV. It will be denoted $H \cdot X$". This means $H \cdot X = Y$.

Comment: I'm so stupid.... many thanks for your answer :)